# How can I write a relation for pivot table in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my table structure:

```
// tickets
+----+------------+----------------------+--------+---------+-------------------+
| id |  subject   |        content       | closed | user_id | unique_product_id |
+----+------------+----------------------+--------+---------+-------------------+
| 1  | subject1   | question1            | 0      | 123     | 2                 |
+----+------------+----------------------+--------+---------+-------------------+

// unique_product
+----+---------------+------------+
| id | serial_number | product_id |
+----+---------------+------------+
| 1  | 2342rd34fc    | 3          |
| 2  | fg34gt4r5t    | 1          |
| 3  | 34ffvv4et6    | 3          |
+----+---------------+------------+

// products
+----+--------------+
| id |     name     | 
+----+--------------+
| 1  | Router-rb51  |
| 2  | Switch-sfx2  |
| 3  | Router-rb300 |
+----+--------------+
```

Now I have a collection of `tickets` like this:

```
$tickets = tickets::where(user_id, "$user_id")->get();
foreach( $tickets as $ticket ){
    $ticket->{I need to get the name of product here}
}
```

I can write a relation in the `tickets` model like this:

```
public function unique_product()
{
    return $this->hasOne(unique_product::class, 'id', 'unique_product_id');
}
```

And I need one more relation to the `products` table for getting the name of product (i.e. `Switch-sfx2`). How should I write that relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tickets = tickets::where(user_id, "$user_id")->with('unique_product.product')->get();
```

You can take advantage eager loading using `with()`.

but for using `with('unique_product.product')` You have to define the relation ships between unique_products and products.

In your UniqueProduct model create a new relationship

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->BelongsTo(Product::class, 'id', 'product_id');
}
```

After that you can access the column of a name like

```
foreach( $tickets as $ticket ){
    $ticket->unique_product->product->name
}
```

Comment: `unique_product` doesn't have `name`. It's a pivot. I need one more join to `Products` table.

Comment: as I mentioned in the answer you can use eager loading. `with('relation')`

Comment: emm .. I don't understand honestly. In where you're joining to `Products` table exactly?

Comment: You have to define relationships in your model.

Comment: I know where should I define relationships. Just I don't see any relation to `Products` table in your approach.

Comment: public function unique_product()
{
    return $this->hasOne(unique_product::class, 'id', 'unique_product_id');
}  You have already defined the relationship.  you just only need eager loading

Comment: Look, there are tree tables: `tickets`, `unique_product`, `products`. That relationship I wrote is a join between `tickets` and `unique_product`. That's it. There isn't any relationship between `unique_products` and `products`. So `$ticket->unique_product->name` returns `NULL`.

Comment: @MartinAJ have a look at my updated answer it may helps you

Comment: Thank you. Just for my information, when I should use `()` in relationships? For example why not `$ticket->unique_product()->product->name`?

Comment: `$ticket->unique_product()` will execute one more query. and you dont want to do this on a loop.